# Parse Android Push Notifcations

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am running Parse on Back4Apps, I have followed their instructions to a T about how to setup push notifications for Android.

http://docs.back4app.com/docs/android/push-notification/send-push-dashboard/

I push a notification from the Parse dashboard and my phone vibrates, it sometimes even shows the notification for 1/2 a second then instantly disappears, so I know my phone is receiving it, what have I missed? Why isn't it displaying?

Many Thanks.

Main Application:

```
  public class MainApplication extends Application {
     public MainApplication()
    {
        instance=this;
    }
    public static Context getContext()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

              // Enable Crash Reporting
        ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .applicationId("blah blah")
                .clientKey("blah blah")
                .server("https://parseapi.back4app.com/")
                .enableLocalDataStore()
                .build());

        ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        installation.put("GCMSenderId", "123456789 etc");
        installation.saveInBackground();


    }
}
```

Build.Gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('src/main/java/libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="adam.exercisedictionary">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="adam.exercisedictionary.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="adam.exercisedictionary.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:name="adam.exercisedictionary.MainApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:largeHeap="true">
<activity
        android:name="adam.exercisedictionary.CategoryList"
        android:label="Gym Exercises">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity"/>
    </activity>
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="adam.exercisedictionary" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:123456789 etc" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works fine. There is something wrong with the device I was testing on. I sent the APK to a few of my friend's Android devices to try and it worked fine, they got alerted. There must be something on my device suppressing notifications, my app is allowed notifications on the device but it just wont work.

Proves a point to test on multiple devices in-case everything looks like it should work and doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to create an Activity that extends AppCompatActivity, rather than a class that extends Application? This might be the issue, as the tutorial you pointed uses that method, rather than this one.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out last night. The code above works fine. There is something wrong with the device I was testing on. I sent the APK to a few of my friend's Android devices to try and it worked fine, they got alerted. There must be something on my device suppressing notifications, my app is allowed notifications on the device but it just wont work.

Comment: I see. Great that you found the problem. I'd try reinstalling the Android SDK